# Building a global vocabulary with a Beam pipeline

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a use case where I need to build a dictionary mapping between the data points and integers, a vocabulary of sorts. To further illustrate this, let's take the following example:

```py
import apache_beam as beam

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  sample = (
      pipeline
      | 'Create produce' >> beam.Create([
          ' Strawberry',
          ' Carrot',
          ' Eggplant',
          ' Tomato',
          ' Potato',
      ])
      | beam.Map(print))
```

If I wanted to create a mapping like `{' Strawberry': 0, ' Carrot': 1, ...}` how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
import apache_beam as beam

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  sample = (
      pipeline
      | 'Create produce' >> beam.Create([
          ' Strawberry',
          ' Carrot',
          ' Eggplant',
          ' Tomato',
          ' Potato',
      ])
      | beam.Map(lambda in: (in.split(' ')[0], in.split(' ')[1]))
      )
```

You'll get `('', 'Strawberry'), ('', 'Carrot'), ('', 'Eggplant'),...`.

These are key-value pairs that you can use later to define your mapping. How do you want ot use it afterwards?

```
  mapping = (
      pipeline
      | 'Create produce' >> beam.Create(['any'])
      | beam.Map(lambda _, sample_dic: sample_dic,
                 beam.pvalue.AsDict(sample))
      | beam.Map(print)
      )
```

This will print the ultimate JSON:

```
{
  '': 'Strawberry',
  '': 'Carrot',
  '': 'Eggplant',
  '': 'Tomato',
  '': 'Potato',
}
```

**NOTE** that the dictionary will be aggregated in a single thread, and if you have a very large amount of data it could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure how would use `('', 'Strawberry'), ('', 'Carrot'), ('', 'Eggplant'),...` to build the mapping mentioned in my question. The end goal is to serialize the mapping as a JSON file inside a GCS Bucket.

Comment: I extended my answer to include that

Comment: Thanks. "NOTE that the dictionary will be aggregated in a single thread, and if you have a very large amount of data it could be a problem." - In that case what would you suggest?